# Is there a faster way to delete table rows so my script doesn't take hours to run?

Tags: excel, office-scripts

My script functions fine when there are only a few rows of data to remove. However, the larger the dataset gets, it becomes slower and unusable. Deleting 50 table rows took multiple hours to run. I think the loop to go through each address in the array is slowing it down, as I can see it deleting one row at a time. However, I am not sure that there is a way to delete all rows in the array without going through a loop.

```
const rowAddressToRemove = rangeView.getRows().map((r) => r.getRange().getAddress());
rowAddressToRemove.splice(0, 1);

const sheet = sourceTable.getWorksheet();

rowAddressToRemove.reverse().forEach((address) => {
sheet.getRange(address).delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
});
```

The current code is working, but it is just slow, and I'm thinking there is something (or some things) horribly optimized in my code that is slowing this down to the point of unusability.

Here is an example of the rowAddressToRemove variable output on the console: (2) ["Pending!A7:G7", "Pending!A8:G8"]
0: "Pending!A7:G7"
1: "Pending!A8:G8"

Comment: Not used office script, but might it be quicker to write the rows you want to a new sheet instead of deleting rows? Append Vs delete and shift-up

Comment: Can you post what's in the `rowAddressToRemove` variable? You can do that by writing a statement like `Console.Log(rowAddressToRemove)`

Comment: Here is an example of the rowAddressToRemove variable output on the console: 
(2) ["Pending!A7:G7", "Pending!A8:G8"]
0: "Pending!A7:G7"
1: "Pending!A8:G8"

Comment: Would it be safe to say that that’s not all of your code? To take multiple hours for 50 rows means there’s something else at play here.

Comment: Correct, it is not all of my code. However, this is the final piece of code in the script. If I remove the portion of code I included here, the script runs quickly. It's the loop of deleting table rows at the end that is making it so slow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this:

```
...getRange(address).delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up)
```

You say that you want to remove entire rows, so why not opt for this:

```
getRange(address).entireRow.delete
```

(I don't know if the `entireRow.delete` needs any arguments, so you might need to see my proposal as pseudo-code)

Comment: I only want to delete the table row. If I use getEntireRow().delete, it will delete the entire row in the worksheet - not just the table row.

Comment: I see. Even then I advise you to gather the different cells within the row and delete all of them together, it will go much quicker.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I agree deleting the cells together is more efficient, and that is what I'd like to find a way to do. Unfortunately, I am not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you're getting row addresses individually instead of getting the address at once. This is for your `rowAddressToRemove` variable. So instead of having code like:

```js
    const rowAddressToRemove = rangeView.getRows().map((r) => r.getRange().getAddress());
```

You can have code like this:

```js
    const rowAddressToRemove = rangeView.getRange().getAddress()
```

So you can try to see if this makes things faster. If it doesn't, it may also have to put the code for your `rangeView` variable in the post as well.